# removing data with tags from a vector

Tags: r

I have a string vector which contains html tags e.g

```
  abc<-""welcome <span class=\"r\"><a href=\"abc\">abc</a></span> Have fun!""
```

I want to remove these tags and get follwing vector

e.g

```
       abc<-"welcome Have fun"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
> gsub("(<[^>]*>)","",abc)
```

what this says is 'substitute every instance of < followed by anything that isnt a > up to a > with nothing"

You cant just do `gsub("<.*>","",abc)` because regexps are greedy, and the .* would match up to the last > in your text (and you'd lose the 'abc' in your example).

This solution might fail if you've got > in your tags - but is `<foo class=">" >` legal? Doubtless someone will come up with another answer that involves parsing the HTML with a heavyweight XML package.

Comment: thank you Spacedman  if the vector contains a hyperlink like a<-c("hello http://abc.com") how can we remove it

Comment: you'll have to stick that example in the question because comments tend to reformat text and muck things up...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your piece of HTML to an XML document with 
`htmlParse` or `htmlTreeParse`.
You can then convert it to text,
i.e., strip all the tags, with `xmlValue`.

```
abc <- "welcome <span class=\"r\"><a href=\"abc\">abc</a></span> Have fun!"
library(XML)
#doc <- htmlParse(abc, asText=TRUE)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(abc, asText=TRUE)
xmlValue( xmlRoot(doc) )
```

If you also want to remove the contents of the links,
you can use `xmlDOMApply` to transform the XML tree.

```
f <- function(x) if(xmlName(x) == "span") xmlTextNode(" ") else x
d <- xmlDOMApply( xmlRoot(doc), f )
xmlValue(d)
```